# query vars in url work but not in ajax call

Tags: ajax

I'm working on ajax script that calls wordpress page and retrieves posts as data.

But I've hit a dead end.

Using: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars

When I directly enter url with query_vars it works and posts get filtered correctly, but when I pass the same using ajax it just lists unfiltered posts. I checked get parameters are getting through, but wp is not catching them.

what should I do?

Code:

http://domain.com/blog/wp-content/themes/wovies-bones/getmovies.php?actor=x And  works fine, I get single post that has custom taxonomy actor = x.

But when I try to load same using ajax, it behaves differently and ignoring my get request returns all posts...

ajax-jquery part:

```
$.ajax({
  url: templatePath + "getmovies.php",
  type: "GET",
  data: filters_get,
  cache: false,
  success: function (data){
    console.dir(data);
  }
});
```

And php part:

```
        /* Define these, So that WP functions work inside this file */
        define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
        require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');


    ?>






        <div id="container">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="movie">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                    <?php
                        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {the_post_thumbnail('homepage-preview');}
                        else {echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/default-poster.jpg" />';}
                    ?>
                    <p class="comments"><?php comments_number('0 review','1 review','% reviews'); ?></p>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <!-- No movies found -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- End #container -->
```

filters_get looks like this: ?actor=x&

Comment: Please link to or provide source of said script.

Comment: @Rarst done. :)

Comment: what is the value of `filters_get`? though you may be able to eventually get this to work, it is really the wrong way to do ajax in WordPress. [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and go through the examples.

Comment: jQuery AJAX to a custom (non-WP) PHP file? How is this WordPress related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the right way to specify data.

When you're using jQuery AJAX, you specify data as an *array* or an *object* when passing it in to the method.  In your question, it seems like

```
'filters_get' === '?actor=x&'
```

Instead, you should do the following:

```
filters_get = {
    'actor': 'x'
};

$.ajax({
    url: templatePath + "getmovies.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: filters_get,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data){
        console.dir(data);
    }
});
```

jQuery will internally parse the URL to automatically create the query string args for you.  From the jQuery documentation, the data parameter is:

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.

Your format shouldn't have the `?` in it, because that will break the string. But it's easier to deal with the encoding if you just pass an object (associative array) instead.